# fetch particular column in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am creating a PowerShell Script wherein I have a csv file which consist of few parameters wherein there is a parameter called as status .The ask is whenever the status is Fail ,I want to get the corresponding row. I am using Import-Csv cmdlet in order to fetch the csv file and checking the status if the status is fail or not and based on that I am fetching the corresponding details using the split function but when I am using the split method it is giving me error as

> Method invocation failed because
> [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] does not contain a
> method named 'split'.

Using the below code

```
$Report=(Import-Csv "C:\Users\Documents\Optim_Config_Report_20210216170900.csv")

foreach($i in $Report)
{    
    if($i.Status -eq "Fail")
    {
      $RULE_ID= $i.split(',')[0]
      Write-output $RULE_ID
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me how can I get the corresponding Row details for which the Status is fail?

Report is something like this in a csv format

```
Rule,Id,Category,Sub_Category,System_Value,Risk,Status
1,Operations,Access,Login,High,Pass
2,Operations,Logging,AccessControl,Medium,Pass
3,Operations,encryptions,certificate,High,Fail,
4,Security,Encryption,protcolo,High,Fail
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

For a CSV file named "test.csv" with content like this:

```
"Rule","Id","Category","Sub_Category","System_Value","Risk","Status"
1,Operations,Access,Login,1,High,Pass
2,Operations,Logging,AccessControl,1,Medium,Pass
3,Operations,encryptions,certificate,1,High,Fail
4,Security,Encryption,protcolo,1,High,Fail
```

This script:

```
Import-Csv -Path ./test.csv | Where-Object Status -eq Fail | Format-Table
```

Returns:

```
Rule Id         Category    Sub_Category System_Value Risk Status
---- --         --------    ------------ ------------ ---- ------
3    Operations encryptions certificate  1            High Fail
4    Security   Encryption  protcolo     1            High Fail
```

Comment: Thanks for the update.But I am looking for something like whenever the status is Fail , I want to fetch the corresponding column attribute details like $Rule_Id,$Category,Sub_Category,$#System_Value,$Risk,$Status.

The reason why I am fetching the corresponding details is I want to use these details in the html code for which I will be placing these values and from there it will generate a html code rather than a csv as an output.

Comment: I put your example data (which I modified to add a System_Value column data value - your header had 7 columns but your data had 6). The `Format-Table` isn't needed if you want to use something like `ForEach-Object` to iterate the result.

Answer (score 0):

When you `Import-CSV`, you are creating an array of `[PSCustomObject]`s, each of which has properties corresponding to the names of the columns in the CSV. For your example, those properties will be `Rule`, `ID`, `Category`, `Sub_Category`, `System_Value`, `Risk`, and `Status`.

It is not clear from your example what information you wish to report in the event of a status of `Fail`, but all you need to do is reference the properties that contain that information - for example, if I wanted to report the `Category` and `Sub_Category`, I might use

```
...
if ($i.status -eq "Fail") {
    Write-Host $i.Category, $i.Sub_Category
}
...
```

Which would, for your sample data, output

`encryptions certificate`
`Encryption protcolo`